# How do I get the root index page to redirect to a subdirectory without affecting SEO?

Tags: seo, redirects

I am reviving/reorganising my personal WordPress blog.

It's using a URL that looks like this:

`http://mydomain.com/blog`

The webserver 301 redirects `www.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com`.

I want to use the `blog` subdirectory because I plan to add other parts to the site, with the blog only being one part of the site.

However, at the moment there is nothing there but the blog, so I want to have the root index page redirect to the blog for the time being.

I have been using this on the root `index.html` page to do the redirect...

`<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=./blog">`

...but this seemed to have stopped the site being indexed by Google and Bing.

How do I do this without affecting SEO?  Also, what URL should I put in the `sitemap.xml`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could rewrite URLs internally in your root .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On

#if request is mydomain.com/something OR
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [OR]

# or www.mydomain.com/something
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com$

# but not mydomain.com/blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/

#change it to mydomain.com/blog/something
RewriteRule (.*) /blog/$1 [R=301]
```

Or, if you want to apply a temporary solution till you develop the other parts of site, you could place an `index.php` in the root with this following code:

```
<?php
Header( "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently" ); 
Header( "Location: http://www.mydomain.com/blog" ); 
?>
```

Benefits of this approach is that no present/possible messing up of URLS. And it is simpler than `.htaccess` approach. Also this will tell Google that this page moved permanently ( or temorary with 302) to this new location. (Although `[R=301]` in `.htaccess` would have done same thing.)

Here is a [discussion about 301 & 302 redirects by Matt Cutts](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/seo-advice-discussing-302-redirects/)

Comment: Updated with `php redirect` approach.

Comment: I like the way the .htaccess method is working, but I am not sure how the it is going to be indexed, as Google may not like the fact that `http://mydomain.com` and `http://mydomain.com/blog` are exactly the same.  Does what I out in the `sitemap.xml` make a difference to what and how it is going to be indexed?

Comment: Sorry, no SEO expert.. But you could use Flag `301` (`Moved Permanently`) in `.htaccess` code. It tells Google & other visitors/browsers that `mydomain.com` is permanently moved to `mydomain.com/blog` Updated .htaccess code with this change.

Comment: Regarding the URL you use in sitemap.xml it would make sense to only include the URL that you are actually serving content from and the one that will appear in the SERPS, ie. `http://mydomain/blog/`.

Comment: @Davinder: I'm using the `index.php` method (the `.htaccess` method causing other directories to be inaccessible).  I'm sure, but it looks like all pages but the homepage has been wiped off Google SERPs, just like they were when I was using the `meta refresh` method I mentioned in the question. So is Google does not index 301 redirects?  I feel like I'm back to square one.

Comment: It takes time for Google to fully index 301 redirects (up to weeks).